# Trigger a function from father component - that will run componentDidMount at child's component

Tags: node.js, reactjs

so i got this React project - there is an admin page and i can add new vacations (with Reactstrap Modal).
the Vacations are added to the database and are shwon in a child's component called AdminVacations.
the array of the Vacations is loaded at the child's component.
this is the code to add Vacation (in admin component)

```
 async Add (){
        let NewVac = {
        name:this.state.name,
        price:this.state.price,
        start:this.state.start,
        end:this.state.end,
        image:this.state.file,
        description:this.state.description
        }

        let r = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/addvacation`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(NewVac)
          });
        let jsonData= await r.json(); 
        if (r.status === 200){
            this.toggle();

        }

    }
```

i also got edit and delete buttons - which found in the child's child component.
the problem is that i need to show the changes on the screen(Live).
 i manage to do it with the edit and delete button (because they are found in the same component)
but the add button is not there.
how can i make the Vacations state be reloaded again in the child's component from his father component?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import apiUrl from './apiUrl';
import AdminVacation from './AdminVacation';
import AdminNavbar from './AdminNavbar'


class AdminVacations extends Component {
    state={
        Vacations:[],
        userid:''
    }


    render() {

        return (

           <div className="container">


        <div class="row">
             {this.state.Vacations.map(data=> <AdminVacation key={data.id} data={data} RefreshFunc={this.RefreshFunc.bind(this)}  />)}
        </div>
    </div>
        )
    }

   async componentDidMount(){

    let response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/allvacations`);

    let data = await response.json();

    this.setState({ Vacations:data })

    }

    RefreshFunc(){
        console.log("something Happened")
        this.componentDidMount() 
    }  
}
export default AdminVacations;
```

(basically i want to run componentDidMount in the Child's component (from Admin) again every time i add a Vacation - and not just when i edit it or delte it.
the Edit and Delete are found in AdminVacation Component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) lifecycle method in the child to check for any updates to the `props`. In a nutshell, it works like this. The following code checks if the current props and previous props, with respect to `location` are different, and if so, it performs the actions inside the `if` block.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0); // reset scroll on route change
  }
}
```

Comment: im afraid i didnt really understand how to use it in my code